# Mysq $stmt->execute( array($variable) ); does not work as expected

Tags: mysql

Mysql named `2_1_paidused`

```
NumberRenamed | Active
-----------------------
 40           |  1
 41           |  1
```

Trying to create code that sets `Active` to `0` if `?` contains `NumberRenamed`

Here is code

```
$stmt_test = $db->prepare('UPDATE 2_1_paidused SET Active=0 WHERE NumberRenamed IN (?)');
$stmt_test->execute( array($value_execute_sql_paidused_for_inactive_rows) );
```

and `$value_execute_sql_paidused_for_inactive_rows = '40,41';` .

Or `print_r(array($value_execute_sql_paidused_for_inactive_rows));` is

```
Array ( [0] => 40,41 )
```

As result `0` in column `Active` is set only for `NumberRenamed` 40 and not for 41.

If change code to `$stmt_test = $db->prepare('UPDATE 2_1_paidused SET Active=0 WHERE NumberRenamed IN ('. $value_execute_sql_paidused_for_inactive_rows. ');');`
then all works (in both rows values are set to 0)

What I need to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really want to run this query:

```
UPDATE 2_1_paidused SET Active=0 WHERE NumberRenamed IN ('40,41')
```

You possibly want to use **two** parameters:

```
UPDATE 2_1_paidused SET Active=0 WHERE NumberRenamed IN (?, ?)
```

... and then call `execute()` with a two-item array.